# How can I enable Safari 13.1 (Catalina) to render specific unicode characters?

Tags: safari, catalina, unicode

Since upgrading to macOS Catalina (10.15.4) I realized that Safari (13.1) can no longer render my lovely [black truck](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26df/index.htm)(⛟). If I inspect this element in the developer console or copying the character into the url bar, everything is rendered perfectly fine, but in the web view, I only get the [white square](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm) displayed. The same problem exists on 2 other Catalina machines, but not on the 10.14 and 10.13 Safaris.

How can I fix this on Catalina?

Answer (score 2):

Display of unicode characters in any app normally requires that a font with that character be installed on the machine.  Black Truck (U+26df) is not in any MacOS font for 10.13, 10.14, or 10.15 as far as I can tell, so you would need to install one of those mentioned on [this page](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26df/fontsupport.htm) to see it.

MS Word comes with one of them,  Segoe UI, so if that app is present and that font is available to other apps, then you should be able to see 26df (⛟).

Comment: ⛟⛟⛟ I've added Symbola to my 10.15.3. The truck shows in this comment but not in my answer proper or the question. In 10.13.6, with the same font added, the truck shows up everywhere.  So something is amiss in the latest Safari, which Apple needs to fix.

Comment: you can see the trucks in your comment?!? This is even more strange. Even if I force Safari (via dev console + css) to use Symbola, the truck is not displayed for me (in your comment or one mine). Thanks for your acknowledgment of this problem.

Comment: @xiconfjs With Symbola installed, can you see the truck in other apps, like Mail, Notes, TextEdit, Message, Pages?

Comment: yes, indeed. Even in the developer console of safari -> https://imgur.com/a/QdOOGRS